# Unable to run commands with neovim, when launched from git bash

Tags: git-bash, neovim

I am trying to run terminal commands from neovim. I launched nvim from git bash. But when I run `:!ls` I get the error

: /usr/bin/bash: /s: No such file or directory

shell returned 127

I searched the internet, I couldn't find the solution. Can anybody help me with this??

Specs: I installed both git and neovim from the websites.
OS: Windows 11.

Running bash commands from neovim would be a useful feature that improves my productivity.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually a same [issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/14605) on Neovim’s GitHub.

Try add `set shellcmdflag=-c` to your config file.

Comment: It works, but not always, as a temporary solution can be used in init.vim :let &shell = '"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"'